# How to check all tabs of specific site are closed

Tags: javascript

I am setting a variable in local storage when my website is loaded. Now I want to remove this variable only after all tabs of my website are closed.

For example I open the home page in one tab, at that time I will set the variable in local storage. After that, I open a product detail in another tab. This time there is no need to set the variable again because it is already set. Now if I close all the tabs(home page, product detail page) then only the variable should be removed from local storage.

Is there any approach I can try? Please suggest.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to increment an integer in your localStorage each time an onglet is open. So everything will be close when the value return to 1

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you **can't**. Or to be more precise HTTP is a stateless protocol, meaning you can't tell if a user has closed their browser tab or simply sitting doing nothing.

There are however *tricks* you could use to identify how many tabs the user has open. One example is to keep a tab counter stored in user's local storage and increment it on each page load, and decrease it on page unload like [@martin karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6215492/martin-karl) mentioned.

<strike>You could use Jquery [unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) event to detect when user closes his tab.</strike> Deprecated since Jquery 1.8.

Now you can use [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event.